# Bags from Mexico to Hawaii

Tags: luggage

Flying from Cancun to Hawaii, I have a 7 hr. Layover. Do I check my bags all the way or recheck them in the morning. I am going to a hotel for the night.

Comment: Is it the same booking the whole way through? Which airlines? Where is the layover? More details would go a long way...

Comment: Where is your layover?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your layover is in the US, you will not be permitted to check your bags all the way through.  When you land at the first stop, you will be required to reclaim your baggage, go through customs, then re-check your bags before boarding the flight to Hawaii.

If you happen to go to a hotel between customs and re-checking your bags, I'm sure nobody will even notice.

Comment: @choster: I understand, but that's *probably* irrelevant to the question... unless they do something to ensure that you don't leave the airport with your bags, or that you don't open your bag.

Comment: Ah, I missed that there was an overnight involved.